# emacs key "deletechar"?

Tags: emacs, key

which is emacs key <deletechar>?

Is there any emacs command to check specified character name?

There are two keys mapped to `delete-char` functions: Delete, and <deletechar>. 
Delete key I have remapped, so <deletechar> left, but I can't figure out which one it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Emacs, "delete" and "deletechar" are not specific keyboard keys, they are mapped to specific "key sequences". If you look at the content of the local-function-key-map variable, you may see that "deletechar" is mapped to other "key sequences". Looking at the content of the function-key-map variable will show you what terminal device mapping is in place. The variables key-translation-map and input-decode-map may also have an entry for "deletechar".

If you use both terminal and windowed versions of emacs or you use different terminal types or if you use emacs on different hardware platforms or if you use different versions of emacs, you may find that pressing a keyboard key sometimes generates a "delete" key sequence and sometimes it will generate a "deletechar" key sequence depending on what the specific key sequence mappings are. Therefore, if you have set "delete" to execute one function and "deletechar" to execute another function, the actual function that is executed may vary depending on whether you are running on terminal or windowed emacs, the terminal type, and the version of emacs.

For more info, have a look at the [Keymaps for Translating Sequences of Events](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Translation-Keymaps.html) section of the Emacs manual and the links off the [Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Keymaps.html#Keymaps) section of the Emacs manual.